# Transit in Doha without visa

Tags: transit, india, covid-19, doha, syrian-citizens

Since Qatar is the only Gulf country that hasn't banned travel from India yet.

I am a non-Indian living in India, and I booked a ticket from India to Doha through Indigo and another ticket from Doha to Damascus.

The question is can I transit in Doha for 4 hours waiting for the second flight?
Or will I be allowed to board the plane to Doha, knowing that I don't have Visa in Qatar?

Comment: Will you be able to transit airside?

Comment: Of what country are you a citizen? What airline will provide the India > Qatar flight? What airline will provide the Qatar > Syria flight?

Comment: I am a Syrian citizen, I will be taking Indigo from India to Doha

From Doha to Damascus, SyrianAir.
@DavidSupportsMonica

Comment: @Traveller That is indeed the question.

Comment: Information available online is contradictory. You might be able to find a answer by asking IndiGo (perhaps in person at the departure airport) or by entering your personal data on IATA's "Passport, Visa, and Health Regulations" tab [on this page](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com).

Comment: Thank you, from what I saw on the website in your comment, it is possible to do so. And after I canceled my ticket, I got a reply to my query from the airport stating that I don't need a visa and that I have to confirm that from the airline company. @DavidSupportsMonica